# Derivative of function with respect to function of function

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives

If I have a function $f$ of $g$ where $g$ is also a function of $f$, is it possible to find $\frac{df}{dg}$? In my eyes, the problem is that one would have some kind of "infinite chain rules" problem, as you want to find

$\frac{df(g(f(g(f(g(f(g...)}{dg(f(g(f(g(f(g...)}$

or am I mistaken? To give an explicit example, consider the following system of equations:

$ W = \frac{\sum_i x_iw_i(x_i)}{\sum_i x_i} $

$ x_1 = W(x_1) * \frac{\gamma_1(x_1)}{\delta_1(x_1)}$

Is it possible to find $\frac{dx_1}{dW}$ ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no sense to take a derivative with respect to a function(*). Remember what a derivative is: it's a limit $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. You can make $f$ a complicated expression involving the composition of a lot of functions, but at the end of the day you are taking the derivative with respect to some *variable* $x$ (and fixing everything else).

If $f(x) = F(x, g(x))$ and $g(x) = G(x, f(x))$ both depend on $x$ and each other, you can still compute the (total) derivative:

$$\frac{df}{dx} = D_1F + D_2F\frac{dg}{dx} = D_1F + D_2F(D_1G + D_2 G \frac{df}{dx}$$
where $D_i$ means partial differentiation with respect to the $i$th parameter; you shouldn't think of this as "infinite recursion"(**) but rather as a linear equation relating $\frac{df}{dx}$ to some other functions. You can even solve for $\frac{df}{dx}$:
$$\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{D_1F + D_2FD_1G}{1-D_2FD_2G}.$$

As for your example, I'm not ever sure what you mean by the notation $\frac{dx_1}{dW}$. My best guess is that you want to use the inverse function theorem to write $x_1$ as a function of $W$ (holding all of the other $x_i$ fixed), which you can do from your first equation, but then I'm not seeing where the second equation comes in, or the "infinite chain rule."

(*) Well you *can*, in the context of the calculus of variations, but that's not what you mean here.

(**) Setting aside the question of how you plan to evaluate $f$ or $g$ in the first place.

Comment: are you sure that we can't consider a derivative with respect to a function? e.g. if $f(x)=log^2(x)$ assuming log(x) as variable then $\frac{df}{dlogx}=2log(x)$

Comment: @gimusi people do write this kind of thing, but it's juggling with lit dynamite and not something I recommend. What's really going here is that you're introducing a new variable $y = \log x$, and computing $\frac{df}{dy} = \frac{\partial \log^2 x}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial \log^2 x}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dy}.$

Comment: I really do not like to write down this king of stuff but I think that is not completely uncorrect :). Thanks!

Comment: @gimusi I wouldn't say it's incorrect... any notation is "correct" if you carefully define what you mean by it. On the other hand, this notation lends itself so easily to confusion (especially once you start involving multiple variables) that IMO it's best to just avoid it completely.